# Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/FontIcon'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui, package.json

I have checked on my node module, FontIcon folder not present, its missing, I have tried many thinks but problem not resolved, Please help me.
My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "flipshop",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.40",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: which version of material-ui do you use

Comment: "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.40"

Comment: One more think, Some time when i install material UI after installation in node module it's show empty folder ,, Why

Comment: Not sure why it would result in an empty folder. However to solve your FontIcon you can check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FontIcon is not an export in `material-ui` version `1.0.0-beta.40`, you need to make use of Icons

To use `FontIcons`, include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

in your project and then

To use an `icon` simply wrap the icon name (font ligature) with the `Icon` component, for example:

```
import Icon from 'material-ui/Icon';

 ...
<Icon>star</Icon>
```

Check the **[documentation](https://material-ui-next.com/style/icons/#font-icons)**

Comment: Entire library has been refactored, I would suggest you to go through the updated documentation